# C# Update fields belonging to the Id in the query string

Tags: c#

I m a newbie to C# and Ive got this doubt please help.
I have these 2 webpages  lets call them pageA and pageB .PageA has got a table(used DataGrid) displaying all the fields of a table in sql server ,it has got an additional edit column which displays a link to PageB, the url for pageB has got a query string which contains the ID of the product that is to be updated .In PageB i have got an update form. The form fields of which is already filled (i.e im retrieving data using the ID from the query string using "select").This pageB has got a button which is supposed to update the fields that were edited in this page and store them back to the server . 
In pageB :the Page_Load() is where i save the ID to a variable (VarID) and i call the method fill_data_fields() which does the "select" and fills the fields .I ve also got the update_click() which is called when i click the button on pageB it is in this method I ve written the code to update the fields in database .
The PROBLEM is ,that the method update_click() is never called when i click the button.

Comment: you'll want to provide some code related to the problem you're having...btw, are you using asp.net? why not the new/(muchbetter) asp.net mvc ??

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that you're adding the button programmatically rather than defining it in the asmx markup?  ASP.Net is horrible with dealing with that issue.  Also make sure you've wired your update_Click() button correctly in the asmx markup as well.  Remember, C# is case sensitive!